# How can I check a WheelEvent is from mouse wheel or touchpad in qml on Windows?

Tags: qt, qml

I tried this `var isTrackPad = wheel.pixelDelta !== Qt.point(0,0);` as [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-wheelevent.html#pixelDelta-prop) says.

But it seems pixelDelta works only on Mac. Is there other method to check if a wheel event is from mouse wheel or touchpad on Windows?

```
onWheel: {
    var horizontal = false;
    var isTrackPad = wheel.pixelDelta !== Qt.point(0,0);

    if (Math.abs(wheel.angleDelta.x) > Math.abs(wheel.angleDelta.y)) {
        delta = wheel.angleDelta.x
        horizontal = true
    }
    else {
        delta = wheel.angleDelta.y
    }
    if ((isTrackPad && horizontal) || (!isTrackPad && wheel.modifiers === xxx.ScrollModifiersH)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `WheelHandler` instead like the following. I can't tell if it will work on Windows as I'm using Linux and there the Mouse is the same as the Touchpad.

[acceptedDevices](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-wheelhandler.html#acceptedDevices-prop)

> Note: Some non-mouse hardware (such as a touch-sensitive Wacom tablet,
> or a Linux laptop touchpad) generates real wheel events from gestures.
> WheelHandler will respond to those events as wheel events even if
> acceptedDevices remains set to its default value.

```
WheelHandler {
    acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.Mouse
    onWheel: console.log("WheelHandler", "Mouse")
}

WheelHandler {
    acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.TouchPad
    onWheel: console.log("WheelHandler", "TouchPad")
}
```

---

Or you can get the [QInputDevice::DeviceType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputdevice.html#DeviceType-enum) from the [WheelEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-wheelevent.html). But same story here, if your OS doesn't make a difference between mouse or touchpad it will always give you `QInputDevice::DeviceType::Mouse`. The matching enum in QML is `PointerDevice.Mouse`.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onWheel: function(wheelEvent) {
        console.log("device", wheelEvent.device.type)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any thing about `wheelEvent.device` in [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-wheelevent-members.html). Did I miss anything?

Comment: I tried these two with Thinkpad, It's not working... There's only mouse device on Windows...

Comment: The device property is undocumented. I've looked it up in the [source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/kernel/qevent.h?h=dev#n279).

Comment: I always got mouse type on Windows as well.